# If Else Radio boxes assigning variables

Tags: variables, if-statement, radio-button

Small example of a larger piece of code i'm trying to get working.

I am very new, but i'm able to take critism.

```
<script>

        var costPeeler;
        var costCutter;
        var costMachine;
        var machineType;

function totalIt() {

        var costPeeler = 5850;
        var costCutter = 4950;
        var machineType = document.getElementById("machineType").value;         

         if (machineType=peelerType) {
     var costMachine = costPeeler;
     } else if (fryType=cutterType) {
     var costMachine = costCutter;
     } else {
     var costMachine = costPeeler + costCutter;  
        }

}

</script>

<form>

    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="peelerType" checked onkeyup="totalIt();">Potato Peeler
    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="cutterType" onkeyup="totalIt();">Potato Fry Cutter
    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="bothType" onkeyup="totalIt();">Both
</form>

  <input name="costMachine" id="costMachine">
```

If anyone could offer tips or suggestions, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

---

Really appreciate the suggestions! that was exactly what I was doing wrong.

Problem, I merged the new info with my full code, and it's not working.
I've gone through it so many times, I can't find the issue

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function totalIt() {

    var costPeeler = 6350;
    var costCutter = 5495;
    var hourlyPay = 10.25;
    var benefit = 1.1;

    var hoursWorked = 0;
    var costTotal = 0;
    var costPound = 0;
    var consumption = 0;
    var costMachine = 0;
    var cost50 = 0;
    var hoursWorked = 0;
    var fridgeCost = 0;
    var cost1year = 0;
    var saving1year = 0;
    var saving2year = 0;
    var savingMonth = 0;
    var returnOnI = 0;
    var saving20year = 0;
    var laborbenefitsCost = 0;
    var materialslaborCost = 0;

    var potatoUse = document.form1["potatoUse"].value; 
    var fryType = document.form1["fryType"].value;         
    var machineType = document.form1["machineType"].value;         

    if (fryType=="frozenType") {
         var cost50 = 50;
         var hoursWorked = 0;
         var fridgeCost = 1;
    } else if (fryType=="unwashedType") {
         var cost50 = 10;
         var hoursWorked = 0.75;
         var fridgeCost = 0;
    } else {
         var cost50 = 17;    
         var hoursWorked = 0.25;
         var fridgeCost = 0;
    }

    if (machineType=="peelerType") {
        costMachine = costPeeler;
    } else if (machineType=="cutterType") {
        costMachine = costCutter;
    } else {
        costMachine = costPeeler + costCutter;  
    }


    var laborCost = hourlyPay * hoursWorked + 0;
    var laborbenefitsCost = laborCost * 0.1 + laborCost + 0;
    var materialslaborCost = cost50 + laborbenefitsCost;
    var costsTotal = materialslaborCost + fridgeCost;
    var costPound = costsTotal / 50;
    var consumption = potatoUse * 52;
    var cost1Year = costPound * consumption;
    var costSaving = costMachine + 0.21 * consumption;
    var saving1year = cost1year - costSaving;
    var saving2year = cost1year - costsaving - costMachine;
    var savingMonth = saving2year / 12;
    var returnOnI = costMachine / savingMonth;
    var saving20year = saving2year * 19 + saving1year;

  document.getElementById("costMachine").value = costMachine;
  document.getElementById("cost50").value = cost50;
  document.getElementById("hoursWorked").value = hoursWorked;
  document.getElementById("fridgeCost").value = fridgeCost;
  document.getElementById("hourlyPay").value = hourlyPay;
  document.getElementById("hoursWorked").value = hoursWorked;
  document.getElementById("costTotal").value = costTotal;
  document.getElementById("costPound").value = costPound;
  document.getElementById("consumption").value = consumption;
  document.getElementById("cost1year").value = cost1year;
  document.getElementById("saving1year").value = saving1year;
  document.getElementById("saving2year").value = saving2year;
  document.getElementById("savingMonth").value = savingMonth;
  document.getElementById("returnOnI").value = returnOnI;
  document.getElementById("saving20year").value = saving20year;


    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">

<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center">Weekly Potato Use:      
      <input name="potatoUse" id="potatoUse" onKeyUp="totalIt();" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="peelerType" checked onClick="totalIt();" />Potato Peeler
      <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="cutterType" onClick="totalIt();" />Potato Fry Cutter
      <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="bothType" onClick="totalIt();" />Both</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="fryType" value="frozenType" checked onClick="totalIt();" />Frozen French Fries
      <input type="radio" name="fryType" value="unwashedType" onClick="totalIt();" />Raw Unwashed Potatoes
      <input type="radio" name="fryType" value="washedType" onClick="totalIt();" />Raw Washed Potatoes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cost of 50 lbs</td>
      <td>Total Costs</td>
      <td>Cost per Pound</td>
      <td>Machine Cost</td>
      <td>Total Operating Costs 1 year</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="cost50" id="cost50"></td>
      <td><input name="costTotal" id="costTotal"></td>
      <td><input name="costPound" id="costPound"></td>
      <td><input name="costMachine" id="costMachine"></td>
      <td><input name="cost1year" id="cost1year"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1st Year Savings</td>
      <td>2nd Year Savings</td>
      <td>Savings per Month</td>
      <td>Return on Investment</td>
      <td>Total Savings (20 Years)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="saving1year" id="saving1year"></td>
      <td><input name="saving2year" id="saving2year"></td>
      <td><input name="savingMonth" id="savingMonth"></td>
      <td><input name="returnOnI" id="returnOnI"></td>
      <td><input name="saving20year" id="saving20year"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. document.getElementById("machineType") references an ID that doesn't exist on the page
2. var costMachine defined in multiple scopes and unusable as currently implemented
3. Assignment operator (=) used instead of equality operator (==)
4. Comparison needs to check against string values
5. keyup event used instead of onclick event
6. input "costmachine" outside of form

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/nozozobi/1/edit?html,js,output) of the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function totalIt() {
    var costMachine = 0;
    var costPeeler = 5850;
    var costCutter = 4950;
    var machineType = document.form1["machineType"].value;         

    if (machineType=="peelerType") {
        costMachine = costPeeler;
    } else if (machineType=="cutterType") {
        costMachine = costCutter;
    } else {
        costMachine = costPeeler + costCutter;  
    }

  document.getElementById("costMachine").value = costMachine;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="peelerType" checked onclick="totalIt();" />Potato Peeler
    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="cutterType" onclick="totalIt();" />Potato Fry Cutter
    <input type="radio" name="machineType" value="bothType" onclick="totalIt();" />Both

    <input name="costMachine" id="costMachine" value="5850" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd also suggest replacing your if-else-if pattern with a switch statement, adding label tags, and dynamically loading the peeler price rather than hardcoding it, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to understand:
1) Assignment Operator
2) Conditional Operator

For conditions, you use conditional operator not assignment operator. Because if you use assignment operator like you have used above, it will always be TRUE

```
if (machineType=peelerType) {
```

This should be

```
    if (machineType==peelerType) {
....
    else if (fryType==cutterType) {
```